# How does this function's argument change while in a loop?

Tags: function, loops, anonymous-function, currying, nested-function

i'm not sure how to title this because i'm confused about the whole thing.

1) I don't understand how does the numCopy gets it's value when the event is triggered? After the loop executes
2) Does the for loop create 3 different event listeners with 3 different num values?

```
   document.body.innerHTML = '';
   var nums = [1,2,3];    

  nums.forEach(function(val,i){
  var num = nums[i];
        var elem = document.createElement('div');
        elem.textContent = num;
        elem.addEventListener('click', (function(numCopy) {
          return function() {
            alert(numCopy);
          };
        })(num));

        document.body.appendChild(elem);

})
```

Comment: This appears to be a very contrived example. However, it should be noted that there are much better ways of closing over loop variables these days (using `Array.prototype.forEach()` or block-level scoped variables)

Comment: I replaced the for loop with forEach method, but i still don't know what is happening.